# I want to make hh.exe (hh h, htmlhelp) go directly to a website when I run it from a batch (.bat) file

Tags: windows, batch-file, chm

I am sorry for my ignorance, as this is not my area of expertise. Right now I have in my batch file "start hh h"

Can anyone help me and point me in the direction. Just as an example I'd like to open http://google.com in the html help box.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
c:\>hh http://www.google.com
```

pass the web address as parameter and do not skip `http://`

you can try also `mshta http://www.google.com`